# How would I prove this statement using an indirect proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

So I am new to discrete math and I am learning about proofs. I have learned a little about contrapositive and contradiction proofs.

This is the example I have trouble with $$\forall k, l \in \Bbb{Z} \, , \, kl \text{ is even} \implies k \text{ is even } \vee l \text{ is even}.$$

Suppose $k$ is odd and $l$ is odd, then there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $k = 2a + 1$, so $kl = (ab??)$

What I have?

Comment: What do you have?

Comment: If both k and l are not even, then they are all odd, then kl is odd, contradictory to kl  is even.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.  To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs.  For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$.

Comment: @SomeGuy let kj = 2j
let k = 2f+1 

2j=(2f+1)^2 ----> 2j=4f^2 + 4f + 1
solve for k = 2f^2 + 2f + 1/2
not an integer.

Comment: @BrightStar I did let kj = 2j let k = 2f+1 2j=(2f+1)^2 ----> 2j=4f^2 + 4f + 1 solve for k = 2f^2 + 2f + 1/2 not an integer. 

would that be correct?

Comment: Why did you fall to pieces after stating $k = 2a+1$?  Why didn't you go on to state that $l = 2b + 1$?  Then when you multiply $kl$ just plug in $k=2a+1$ and $l= 2b+1$ to get $kl = (2a+1)(2b + 1)$ and... the proof writes itself....

Comment: @fleablood so i would do k = 2a + 1 and l =2b + 1.... kl=(2a + 1)(2b + 1). Then i would factor those out and see if its an integer?

Comment: " I did let $kj = 2j$" No.  If you are assuming $kj$ is even that means there is an $m$ so that $kj = 2m$ but there is no reason to assume that $kj= 2j$. "Let $k = 2f + 1$ so $2j=(2f+1)^2$" Wha...? why would you assume *that*?

Comment: Okay.... no.... You need a strategy.  You must decide *what* you are assuming about *which* numbers and *what* that will show.  You know to prove $kl$ even $\implies k$ even OR $l$ even.  To do a proof by contrapositive you assume ($k$ even OR $l$ even) are both false and show that therefore ($kl$ is even) is not true.  In other words... you assume $k$ and $l$ are both odd... and show that that means $kl$ is odd.  SO if $k=2a+1$ and $l = 2b+1$ then $kl = (2a+1)(2b+1)$.  So now you must show that $(2a+1)(2b+1)$ is odd.  That's all.

Comment: @fleablood the online video i am watching have a similar problem and it is doing it like that. 
So I would do a contrapositive instead of a contradiction or does it not matter?

Comment: ... or... a proof by contradiction would be to assume $kl$ is even, $k$ odd and $l$ odd so $kl = 2m$ and $k = 2a+1$ and $l = 2b+1$ then $2m = kl = (2a+1)(2b+ 1)$ so then ... yes.  You can show that $m = \frac {(2a+1)(2b+1)}2$ is not an integer.  That would work as well.

Comment: You can do *either* but pick a strategy and stick to it.

Comment: @fleablood Ok the notebook im reading doesnt really say when to use one or the other. Is it just that both will usually work? or do you test each of the ways

Comment: A *direct* proof could be. Let $kl = 2m$ by even and $k =2a+1$ is odd. Now show that $l$ must be even.  $l = \frac {2m}{k } = \frac {2m}{2a+1}$.  So $2a+1$ must divide evenly into $2m$. But $2a+1$ is odd so it can't have any factors in common with $2$ so it must divide entirely and evenly into $m$.  So let $\frac m{2a+1} = w$.  Then $l = 2w$ and is even.  (But that may assume a few thing you don't know are feel sure about yet.)

Answer (score 1):

For an indirect proof, we assume the opposite to be true and find a contradiction. This means we assume

$\exists k,l \in \mathbb{Z} : ( 2\mid kl \land 2\nmid k,l)$

Notice that then $k=2a+1$ and $l=2b+1$, therefore $kl=(2a+1)(2b+1)=2(2ab+a+b)+1$ which clearly contradicts the assumption $2\mid kl$

Comment: THANK YOU!!!

I tried another one and its ∀ j ∈ Z if j ∈ Z + and 4j − 1 is prime, then j is odd

I did :
assume j is even 
let j =2k    k∈not Z
2k∈not Z+
4^2k - 1 not Prime

I dont know what to do next

Answer (score 0):

Direct proof:

Strategy: assume $kl$ is even.  Prove that either $k$ is even or $l$ is even.

Proof by contradiction:

Strategy: assume $k$ is odd, $l$ is odd and $kl$ is even.  Get a contradiction (Possibly that $kl =2m$ and $m$ is not an integer.)

Proof by contrapositive

Strategy: assume $k$ is odd, $l$ is odd.  Show that this must mean $kl$ is odd.

.....

The contrapositive proof is (ironically) the most direct and easy.

If $k,l$ are odd there are integers $a,b$ so that $k = 2a + 1$ and $l = 2b+1$.

So $kl = (2a+1)(2b+1) = 4ab + 2a + 2b + 1=2(2ab + a+b) + 1$ is odd.

....

The contradiction proof is similar.

Let $k=2a+1$ and $l = 2b + 1$ and $kl = 2m$ so $2m = (2a+1)(2b+1)$.  The contradiction is RHS is odd and LHS is even.

But it was really unnecessary to assume $kl$ was even.  It added something unnecessary we never really worked with.

....

And direct... not very direct.

Let $kl = 2m$ be even.

The $l = \frac {2m}k=2\frac mk$.

Now either $k$ divides evenly into $m$ or it doesn't.  If it does, then $l$ is even and we are done.

If it doesn't then $\frac mk$ is not an integer but $2\frac mk$ is so $\frac mk = w + \frac 12$ for some integer $w$.  So $m = (w+ \frac 12)k$.  But $m$ is an integer and that can only happen if $k$ is even.

So either $l$ or $k$ is even (or both).

Comment: thank you!!! 

Does what i did for the second problem look correct? The problem is ∀ j ∈ Z if j ∈ Z + and 4j − 1 is prime, then j is odd

I did: assume j is even let j =2k k∈notZ 2k∈not Z+ 4^2k - 1 not Prime

I dont know what to do next

Comment: Just do contrapositive. Assume: $j$ is even. Prove: $4j-1$ is not prime. So let $j=2k$. Plug it in $4j-1=4(2k)-1= 8k-1$. And... well, that can be prime!  Your statement is not true.  Let $j = 6$.  then $4j - 1 = 23$ is prime.  But $j$ is not odd.  So that statement just isn't true.

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall k, l \in \Bbb{Z} \, , \, kl \text{ is even} \implies k \text{ is even } \vee l \text{ is even}.$$

$1)$ A direct proof.

> When proving a proposition of the form $p \implies q$ using the method of direct proof, you assume that $p$ is true and, with this assumption, you show (directly) that $q$ must also be true.

*Proof*. Let $k,l \in \Bbb{Z}$. Suppose that $kl$ is even. Then, $kl = 2j$ for some $j \in \Bbb{Z}$. If $k$ is even, then there is nothing to prove (because $k$ is even $\vee$ $l$ is even is true). Suppose that $k$ is not even. Then, $k$ must be an odd integer. Hence, $k = 2q + 1$ for some $q \in \Bbb{Z}$. Then

\begin{align*}
kl = 2j & \implies (2q+1)l = 2j \\
& \implies 2ql +l = 2j \\
& \implies l = 2j - 2ql \\
& \implies l = 2(j-ql).
\end{align*}

Since, $j-ql \in \Bbb{Z}$ we have that $l$ is an even number and this ends the proof.

$2)$ A contrapositive proof.

> When proving a proposition of the form $p \implies q$ using the method of contrapositive proof, you assume $q$ to be false and, with this assumption, you show that $p$ must also be false. This works because for any two propositions we have that
> \begin{align*}
> (p \implies q) \iff (\sim q \implies \sim p)
> \end{align*}

*Proof*. Let $k,l \in \Bbb{Z}$. Suppose that it is not true that $k$ is even or $l$ is even. Then (by applying the *De Morgan* Law), we conclude that $k$ and $l$ are not even. So, $k$ and $l$ are odd integers. Then, $k = 2j+1$ and $l = 2p + 1$ for some $j,p \in \Bbb{Z}$. Hence,

\begin{align*}
kl = (2j+1)(2p+1) = 4jp + 2j + 2p + 1 = 2(2jp + j + p) + 1.
\end{align*}

Since $2jp+j+p \in \Bbb{Z}$, then $kl$ is an odd integer. So, $kl$ is not even. This ends the proof and result is proved by contrapositive.

$3)$ A *reductio ad absurdum* proof (proof by contradiction).

> When proving a proposition of the form $p \implies q$ using the method of proof by contradiction, we assume that the proposition $p \implies q$ is false (so we assume that $p$ is true and $q$ is false) and then we derive a contradiction. This contradiction comes from assuming that $p \implies q$ is false and therefore we conclude that $p \implies q$ must be true.

*Proof*: Let $k,l \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $kl$ is even. Suppose that $k$ and $l$ are odd integers. Then, $k = 2j$ and $l = 2p+1$ for some $j,p \in \Bbb{Z}$. Hence

\begin{align*}
kl = (2j+1)(2p+1) = 4jp + 2j + 2p + 1 = 2(2jp + j + p) + 1.
\end{align*}

Since $2jp+j+p \in \Bbb{Z}$, then $kl$ is an odd integer. But this is absurd, because it contradicts the fact that $k,l \in \Bbb{Z}$ are such that $kl$ is even. The contradiction came from assuming that $k$ and $l$ are odd integers. Therefore, $k$ is even or $l$ is even.